# how to pass parameters for calling controller's method in Jquery in MVC 3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application. 
I have written a JQuery in view. 
but confused about the passing the parameter...
How to write it ?

View Code------

```
  function ValidateSanctionAmount()
    {

      var amt1=$('#Amount1').val();
      var amt2=$('#Amount2').val();

  var url1 = '@Url.Action("checkPOAmountsValidations", "PaymentAdviceController", new { POId : "a", SanctionedAmt : "b" })';
                        url1 = url1.replace("a",amt1);
                        url1 = url1.replace("b",amt1);

                        url1 = url1.replace("sanctionedAmount",param1);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: url1,
                            type: "GET",
                            success: function (Data) {
                                $('#divNewInvoice').append(Data);
                            }
                        });
```

Controller Code-----

```
   public JsonResult checkPOAmountsValidations(int POId,double SanctionedAmt)
          {
                var oPurchaseOrderHelper = new PurchaseOrderHelper();
                bool b;
                int POId1 =POId;
                double SanctionedAmt1 = SanctionedAmt;

                b = oPurchaseOrderHelper.GetAmountsSumForValidation(POId1, SanctionedAmt1);

                if (b == true)
                {
                    return Json(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(false);
                }

          }
```

------ Code in View
[image]

------Code in Controller

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for the controller please?

Comment: Image is not getting load, please provide text

Comment: I have updated, check now...

Answer (score 2):

Update: Since you are using ajax do this and you don't have to do **url1.replace**

```
var url1 = '@Url.Action("checkPOAmountsValidations", "PaymentAdviceController")';
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    data : JSON.stringify({ POId : amt1, SanctionedAmt: amt2 }),
    dataType : "JSON",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (Data) {
        $('#divNewInvoice').append(Data);
    }
});
```

Old:

try this, JavaScript doesn't execute when generating the action URL.

```
function ValidateSanctionAmount()
{
    var amt1=$('#Amount1').val();
    var amt2=$('#Amount2').val();

    var url1 = '@Url.Action("check", "controller1", new { param1= "-1", param2= "-1" })';
    url1 = url1.replace("-1",amt1);
    url1 = url1.replace("-2",amt2);
}
```

Controller method:

```
public class controller1: Controller
{
    public ActionResult check(double param1, double param2)
    {
        //Do whatever
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to pass amt1, amt2 to method

Comment: what is Paeam1 and Param2 ? where it should be declare ? showing error in the code Param1,Param2 does not exist in current context